# How to load data from multiple CSV files into nested dictionary?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have multiple CSV files that have a date as the filename (dd-mm-yyyy.csv). All files are in the following format, including also date value as a column value:

```
date,        id,     name,   value1, value2, value3
03-09-2020,   3,     ACME,     123,    456,    789
```

How could I merge my data across all the files in one directory into nested dictionary based on the id? For example for id=3 it would look like:

```
dictionary = {'id': 3 
{name: 'ACME' 
{'date': '03-09-2020' {'value1': 123, 'value2': 456, 'value3': 789}}
{'date': '02-09-2020' {'value1': 987, 'value2': 654, 'value3': 321}}
{'date': '01-09-2020' {'value1': 231, 'value2': 564, 'value3': 979}}}}
```

My aim is to merge all files with daily data into one master file. Could someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using a nested dictionary isn't really necessary and unless you need it for something else it is quite impractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to merge all the files:

```
import os

files = os.listdir(directory) # insert your directory
files = [file for file in files if '.csv' in file]

cols = []
data = []

for file in files:
    with open(directory + '/' + file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().split('\n')
        cols = text[0].replace(' ', '')
        data += text[1:-1] # remove column names and blank at end of csv

data = [line.replace(' ', '').split(',') for line in data] # assuming there is a comma and tab between columns
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), x[2], x[0])) # sort data by id, then name, then date

with open('master.csv', 'w+') as f:
    data = [cols] + [','.join(line) for line in data]
    f.write('\n'.join(data))
```

Comment: Hi hhaefliger, for some reason I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '04-08-2020.csv'`but my file is in the selected directory. Would you know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: it throws this error after running this loop: for file in files:

Comment: Hi sorry about that, I forgot to add directory/ before

Comment: I've fixed it now

Comment: thank you for your help! the loop worked now and I got until this moment: `data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), x[2], x[0]))` after running this it says `IndexError: list index out of range` I'm wondering if I should change anything in this line?

Comment: full error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: could you print line[0] of data

Comment: make sure that there is a comma and a tab between each column in the files

Comment: just checked. It is that

Comment: it should work now. I also made it remove the inconsistent spacing from the final file

Comment: it worked! but now when saving the output it says: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: Just fixed that as well, I had inverted the items passed to the join function

Comment: It produced an empty csv file. Would you be able to help with this? There wasn't any error message this time.

Comment: never mind! I was doing something wrong :) it worked! thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, no problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following structure:

```
d={3 : {'name':'ACME', 'values':{ 
'03-09-2020': {'value1': 123, 'value2': 456, 'value3': 789},
'04-09-2020': {'value1': 100, 'value2': 200, 'value3': 300}, 
.....}}}
```

And the code to build this is the following

```
import pandas as pd:
def load_file(file):
    df=pd.read_csv('newcv.txt', sep=',')

    for i in range(len(df)):
        d[df['id'].iloc[i]]['name']=df['name'].iloc[i]
        d[df['id'].iloc[i]]['values'][df['date'].iloc[i]['value1']=df['value1'].iloc[i]]
        d[df['id'].iloc[i]]['values'][df['date'].iloc[i]['value2']=df['value2'].iloc[i]]
        d[df['id'].iloc[i]]['values'][df['date'].iloc[i]['value3']=df['value3'].iloc[i]]
```

You can run this function for the files in your directory

Comment: Hi archer, thank you for your help so far. I've tried the code above and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and arrow pointing to the bracket at the end of this row: `d[df['id'].iloc[i]]['values'][df['date'].iloc[i]]['value1']=df['value1'].iloc[i]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample dictionary is not valid so not requires interpretation.

I recommend using a combination of `set_index()` a `lambda` function to generate `dict` of values and then `to_dict()`

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""date,id,name,value1,value2,value3
03-09-2020,3,ACME,123,456,789
02-09-2020,3,ACME,987,654,321"""), sep=",")
(df.set_index(["id","date"])
 .assign(values=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: {k:v for k,v in r.items() if "value" in k}, axis=1))
 .loc[:,["name","values"]]
 .to_dict(orient="index")
)
```

**output**

```
{(3, '03-09-2020'): {'name': 'ACME',
  'values': {'value1': 123, 'value2': 456, 'value3': 789}},
 (3, '02-09-2020'): {'name': 'ACME',
  'values': {'value1': 987, 'value2': 654, 'value3': 321}}}
```